# bind my java function to saxon XSLT processor

Tags: java, xslt

I have my own java static function in a class:

```
package com.test;

public class A {

    public static void returnSameNodes(Object nodes){
        return nodes;
    }


}
```

I tried to bind this function to XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:ext="java:com.test.A" >
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:returnSameNodes(//child::*)"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

, but with the following error:

> Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named etc.

I know what I'm doing wrong - I have to tell saxon(9B) that my class is in particular location, but I don't know how to do this. Any suggestions?? Including for example Math.sqrt() works great. Thanks

EDIT: The problem is setting up Java class path,anybody knows how to do this for this particular case? There is a note in a following link about setting a classpath variable, but how?
http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions.xml 
Thank you for suggestions

Comment: WOW! Let me think for a while

Comment: Can you provide me with some details (API reference, etc.) on how to write custom functions for XSLT in Java? I have never heard of a such possibility in Saxon.

Comment: All right! help is really appreciated

Comment: Are you referring to this? http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions.xml

Comment: http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html nice article but:)

Comment: Oh right, this as well: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions/staticmethods.xml

Comment: Could it be that calling a static method is not supported in Saxon(9B)? http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2910430&group_id=29872&atid=397617

Comment: "Binding the extensions to the stylesheet. This is done via namespaces, class names, and the Java class path."   I have first two done 100% correctly, I'm not sure how to do the third.

Comment: This is for saxon 9.2 I'm on saxon 9, the way of calling extension functions changed a lot: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I wish I could help you more!

Comment: This happens,thank you anyway

Comment: No problems. Hope you can resolve the problem!

Comment: Setting the class path all depends on how you are running your program. You'll need to provide more details about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running from the command line, then

(a) use the -TJ option to get better diagnostics on problems with extension functions

(b) ensure the class containing your method is on the classpath, for example

java -cp mycode;saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -TJ -xsl:xxx.xsl -s:yyy.xml

where mycode is the directory containing your compiled class

(c) ensure you are using a Saxon release that supports reflexive extension functions (Saxon-HE does not).